# Using minitest to test S3 direct upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, minitest

I'm using direct upload to `AWS S3` to temporarily store files that my website then imports. Anyone got a way to hook this so that I can do `minitest` processing of the website without having to push files to AWS?  FWIW I've been following the Heroku instructions here [Direct to S3 Image Uploads in Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) so my code will look pretty similar to what you see there.

Comment: I've not tried it but I'm considering using Ruby's patching to 'extend' aws-sdk to allow me to return a fake response without actually uploading any files.